# DB2 'SQL0901 SQL System Error.' when trying to SELECT from view containing UNION

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, db2, ibm-midrange

I am using a AS400 DB2 Database. In that Database I got 3 Views.

All Views have the exact same Columnnames and Datatypes.
View 1 & 2 each consist of a Select Statement with aggregate Functions on the same source Table. Just the WHERE Conditions and the aggregate Functions are a little different.

View 3 simply is a UNION SELECT on both VIEW 1 & 2 merging the results.

So here is my Question.

```
SELECT 2 AS CLIENT, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, VALUE 
FROM SOME_DATABASE.VIEW3
WHERE COLUMN1 = @COLUMN1 AND COLUMN2 = @COLUMN2 ORDER BY COLUMN3
```

I can execute parameterized SELECT Statements (like the one above) from my c# Program on VIEW 1 & 2 without problems, but when i try to use a parameterized SELECT on VIEW 3 I get a 'SQL0901 SQL System Error.' However, when i dont use Parameters it just works fine.

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me?

AS400 DB2 Version is v5r2m0
The program is written in c# on .NET 4.0 in VS 2012
using 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll' for accessing the Database

Definition View 1:

```
SELECT  COLUMN1,  
        COLUMN2,  
        COLUMN3,  
        COLUMN4,  
        SUM(CAST((TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,104,1))||TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,94,3))||TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,98,3))||'.'||TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,102,2))) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS VALUE
FROM    SOME_DATABASE.SOME_TABLE  
WHERE   TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,105,3)) <> ''
AND     SUBSTR(COLUMN5,103,5) <> '  EUR'  
AND     COLUMN4 IN ('  $NEHHZ','$NEHHZVE','$NEHWMVE','  $NEHWW','$NEHWWVE','$NEHWWSK',' $NEHKW1',' $NEHKW2',' $NEHSK1',' $NEHSK2','  $NEHNV',' $NEHKZ1',' $NEHLZ1',' $NEHSZ1')  
GROUP BY  COLUMN1,  
        COLUMN2,  
        COLUMN3,  
        COLUMN4
```

Definition View 2:

```
SELECT  COLUMN1,  
        COLUMN2,  
        COLUMN3,  
        COLUMN4,  
        SUM(CAST(TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,109,1))||TRANSLATE(TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,99,10)),'.',',') AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS VALUE  
FROM    SOME_DATABASE.SOME_TABLE  
WHERE   COLUMN6 != 0  
AND     COLUMN4 IN (' SUM$HKV',' SUM$KWZ',' SUM$KZ',' SUM$LZ',' SUM$SZ',' SUM$WMZ',' SUM$WWZ')  
GROUP BY COLUMN1,  
        COLUMN2,  
        COLUMN3,  
        COLUMN4
```

Definition View 3:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, VALUE
FROM SOME_DATABASE.VIEW1
UNION
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, VALUE
FROM SOME_DATABASE.VIEW2
```

Comment: From the documentation: "Another, previously reported error has prevented the processing of a SQL statement. The previous error is logged only in the i5/OS™ job log and is not returned to the ODBC application. You must locate and retrieve the job log to identify and resolve the problem." Can you find the previous error?  More details here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaii%2Frzaiiodbcsql0901.htm

Comment: Well, yes. I know thats only a "wrapper"-Error. But unfortunatetly there is no corresponding entry in the job log of iSeries Navigator.

Comment: Is there some other way of retrieving the DB2 error logs from the AS400?

Comment: On our IBM i these jobs run in the QSYSTEM job queue with the job name QZDASOINIT. You could do a WRKACTJOB, find the right QZDASOINIT job and do a 5 (Work with) and then a 10 to display the job log - IF the job is still active. If it's not then the only log you can look at (that I know of) is QHST. You can do a DSPLOG and select the beginning/ending dates and times so you only have to look through a limited portion of the log.

Comment: I agree with Benny Hill (cue the saxophone music), that you will first need to make the error happen then quickly track down the server job and view the job log.  The ODBC database server jobs on my system are called QZDASOINIT and runs in the QUSRWRK subsystem.  You may see multiple jobs out there, in which case you'll have to look at all of them to find the job servicing your SQL session.  On V5R2 I believe WRKACTJOB will only show you a user of QUSER instead of the actual user currently using that job.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to Benny Hill, i finally found the entries in the Job Log: CPF4204: Message:"Interner Fehler im Abfrageprozessor." and MCH3601: "Zeiger für angegebene Position nicht gesetzt." But i still have no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like parameterized SELECT Statements are not supported with views on views. I just replaced the 3rd View with a statement containing the definition of view 1 UNION view 2 like:

```
SELECT  COLUMN1,  
        COLUMN2,  
        COLUMN3,  
        COLUMN4,  
        SUM(CAST((TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,104,1))||TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,94,3))||TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,98,3))||'.'||TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,102,2))) AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS VALUE
FROM    SOME_DATABASE.SOME_TABLE  
WHERE   TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,105,3)) <> ''
AND     SUBSTR(COLUMN5,103,5) <> '  EUR'  
AND     COLUMN4 IN ('  $NEHHZ','$NEHHZVE','$NEHWMVE','  $NEHWW','$NEHWWVE','$NEHWWSK',' $NEHKW1',' $NEHKW2',' $NEHSK1',' $NEHSK2','  $NEHNV',' $NEHKZ1',' $NEHLZ1',' $NEHSZ1')  
GROUP BY  COLUMN1,  
        COLUMN2,  
        COLUMN3,  
        COLUMN4

UNION

SELECT  COLUMN1,  
        COLUMN2,  
        COLUMN3,  
        COLUMN4,  
        SUM(CAST(TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,109,1))||TRANSLATE(TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN5,99,10)),'.',',') AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS VALUE  
FROM    SOME_DATABASE.SOME_TABLE  
WHERE   COLUMN6 != 0  
AND     COLUMN4 IN (' SUM$HKV',' SUM$KWZ',' SUM$KZ',' SUM$LZ',' SUM$SZ',' SUM$WMZ',' SUM$WWZ')  
GROUP BY COLUMN1,  
        COLUMN2,  
        COLUMN3,  
        COLUMN4
```

And now it just works perfectly. But i still dont understand why this error occured.

Comment: V5R2 is very outdated.  The operating system is now at 7.1 - 4 full releases ahead of that.  On such an outdated system, I would not be surprised to find that the admin hasn't installed any recent cumulative PTFs (service packs).  SQL0901 is an error, and as such should be reported to IBM.  Unfortunately, they will probably tell the admin to upgrade to a modern OS version.  But there may be PTFs already available...

Comment: IBM has ended support for v5r2 years ago.  Their response most likely will be to suggest that you upgrade.  If you want a modern database, you want to get up to v7.1 and stay current on the OS.